# How to setup an alert for the new CDC feature in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create an alert to be notified when the CDC integration runs into an error. But I cannot find any metrics relating to the new CDC feature in the standard list of metrics when I go to create an alert within the Azure Data Factory.

Next, I tried to look at logs to see if I can create an alert based on logs, but I cannot find the table where the logs for the CDC run are being stored. I can see the logs for the standard pipelines run in the ADFPipelineRun table in Log Analytics, but nothing for the new CDC feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current CDC, for both systemError and userError, ADF keep retrying. Once the systemError is resolved, it automatically picks up all the data which has arrived and there is no need for user intervention.

In case of userError, there is no logs available at this point but, ADF product team is working on adding logs and do some action automatically. It is in progress and will be available soon. No definite ETA at this point.

But if you have any additional feedback, please feel free to log it in IDEAS forum here and do share the feedback link back: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c